# Foo Table its not working startly phone screensize

Tags: javascript, jquery, footable

I using footable plugin for my projects.

But ,Its not working startly with phone screen.
Firstly i change screen size from chrome developer tools its workly fine like this,

[image]

but its not working when my codes rework on the phone screen.so like this

[image]

My html code ;

```
       <div id="tablelistDiv">
       <div class="row">
       <table id="tbl_search" class="footable" data-page-size="20">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-toggle="true" data-sort-ignore="false">Sıra No</th>
                <th data-sort-ignore="false">Ünvan</th>
                <th data-hide="phone" data-sort-ignore="false">Şube</th>
                <th data-hide="phone" data-sort-ignore="false">Broker</th>
                <th data-hide="phone" data-sort-ignore="false">Durum</th>
                <th data-hide="phone" data-sort-ignore="false">Kayıt Tar.</th>
                <th data-hide="phone" data-sort-ignore="true"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
          <tfoot>
          <tr>
           <td colspan="7">
             <div class="pagination pagination-centered hide-if-no-paging"></div>
           </td>
          </tr>
         </tfoot>
     </table>
    </div>
    </div>
```

My Js Code is,

```
function detayKayitlar(jsondata, status) {
                    obj = JSON.parse(jsondata);
                    var tableHtml = "";
                    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                        tableHtml = tableHtml
                            + "<tr>"
                            + "<td>" + obj[i].ID + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + obj[i].UNVAN + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + obj[i].SUBE + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + obj[i].BROKER + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + obj[i].USERLASMA + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + obj[i].KAYITTAR + "</td>"
                            + "<td><button onclick='detayKayit(" + obj[i].ID + ",2);' class='btn btn-block btn-danger'  type='button'><i class='fa fa-search'></button></td>"
                            + "</tr>";

                    }

                    $("#tbl_search tbody").append(tableHtml);
                    jQuery(function () {
                        jQuery('#tbl_search').footable();
                    });

                    pWaitHide();
                    hideDiv('search');
                    showDiv('list');
                }
```

Comment: What do you mean with rework? if you doing something dynamically you can run $('#tbl_search').trigger('footable_redraw');

Comment: Hi @almis i try that $('#tbl_search').trigger('footable_redraw'); but I take same result

Comment: Can you make on jsfiddle.net example?

Comment: i think i solved like you said to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what do you mean with rework? if you doing something dynamically you
>   can run $('#tbl_search').trigger('footable_redraw');

from @Almis on first row comment.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since your chrome is in desktop, it is working fine. Please check weather you have added the below line in your header tag or not. This view port will detect the screensize.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```